# How to use pointers with arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting, pointers

I have tried to solve this problem with pointers, but I couldn’t.
The requirement was writing a function in which you see if the array is

- sorted increase (return 1)
- sorted decrease (return -1)
- not sorted at all (return 0)

Here is what I wrote:

```
int *test(int l,int *T)
{
   int i,A[l],sign;
   int *t=&A[0];
   for (i=0; i<l; i++)
   {
       if(A[i]>A[i+1]){
           t++;
       sign =-1;
       }
       if (A[i]<A[i+1]){
           t++;
       sign =1;
       }
       if (A[i]!=A[i+1]){
            t++;
          sign =0;
       }
   }
   return sign;
}
```

The compiler is giving

```
returning ‘int’ from a function with return type ‘int *’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   61 |     return sign;


error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `A[i]>A[i+1]` undefined Behaviour when `i== l-1`

Comment: `int test(int l, int *T) ...` <= remove the star from the return type of the function

Comment: `sign` is `int` you want to return pointer to the `int` (see the star)

Comment: `A` is used not initalized - undefined behaviour

Comment: could you please  tell me what i can do to let the micro pro compare all the elements of the array then return the value

Answer (score 1):

A few things to notice,

- The 'T' parameter wasn't used, so removed.
- The 't' variable wasn't used, so removed.
- The function return type shouldn't be a pointer to integer, it should be just an integer, from your requirements.
- Your code is testing against an array declared in the function scope, and since it is an automatic variable, it is not initialized and may contain garbage values.
- Your code is testing against an out of bounds index when using 'i < len' as the loop condition (ex.: considering that the array length is `3`, when `i == 2`, comparing `a[i]` with `a[i + 1]` would access `a[3]`, which is not within array boundaries that goes from `index 0` to `index 2`.

With that in mind, a possible implementation with some tests is provided below, from what I can see from the requirements list, but bear in mind that I made some assumptions, since there was no restriction about them.

```c
#include <assert.h>

#define SORTED_ASC 1
#define SORTED_DES -1
#define UNSORTED 0

int is_sorted(int *arr, int len)
{
    int sorted = 0;

    // I am assuming that this approach is reasonable, check your requirements.
    if (len <= 1)
        return UNSORTED;

    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {       
        // Previous iteration detected order as 'descending', but current 
        // is 'ascending'.
        if (sorted == SORTED_DES && arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
            return UNSORTED;

        // Previous iteration detected order as 'ascending', but current 
        // is 'descending'.
        if (sorted == SORTED_ASC && arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            return UNSORTED;

        // I am assuming that arrays with repeated values should remain classified 
        // as 'unsorted' until a different value appears, check your requirements.
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            sorted = SORTED_DES;
        else if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
            sorted = SORTED_ASC;
   }

   return sorted;
} 

void test_unsorted()
{
    int arr[4][3] = {
        { 1, 3, 2 },
        { 2, 1, 3 },
        { 2, 3, 1 },
        { 3, 1, 2 }
    };

    for (int row = 0 ; row < 4 ; row++)
    {
        int res = is_sorted(arr[row], 3);
        assert(res == UNSORTED);
    }
}

void test_sorted_ascending()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int res = is_sorted(arr, 3);
    assert(res == SORTED_ASC);
}

void test_sorted_descending()
{
    int arr[] = { 3, 2, 1 };
    int res = is_sorted(arr, 3);
    assert(res == SORTED_DES);
}

void test_with_repeated_values()
{
    int sorted_asc[] = { 1, 1, 2 };
    int sorted_asc_res = is_sorted(sorted_asc, 3);
    assert(sorted_asc_res == SORTED_ASC);

    int sorted_des[] = { 3, 3, 2 };
    int sorted_des_res = is_sorted(sorted_des, 3);
    assert(sorted_des_res == SORTED_DES);

    int unsorted[] = { 1, 1, 1 };
    int unsorted_res = is_sorted(unsorted, 3);
    assert(unsorted_res == UNSORTED);
}

int main(void)
{   
    test_unsorted();
    test_sorted_ascending();
    test_sorted_descending();
    test_with_repeated_values();
}
```

Comment: And last, but not least, the error your compiler is giving is because you are trying to return an integer (int sign) when your return type is an integer pointer ;]